# site navigation in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I am creating simple website in ASP .NET c# for social network, and my question is if I am having a page for groups and for every time user clicks on a group called x for example it should be redirected to the page of group x, how I can do this?
(sorry if I can't explain but am still newbie with ASP .NET)

Comment: asp.net is simply an http pipeline. what framework are you using webforms for an MVC implementation. this will have a huge impact on how you design the site

Comment: @Tarun i can do this, but i think it would be hard to create a page for every created group?

Comment: you wouldn't create a page for every group. you would create a template and load that template based on the users's selection

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to a hyper link

`<a href="group?id=123">My Group</a>`

you will most likely need to change the url and stuff, but basically it's just a link.

Comment: yea that's exactly what I mean, but could you please tell me about a site or something to read more about this?

Comment: this is HTML 101 any beginner's guide would be enough to get you started. I would start by learning html, css, js, then introduce your server technology of choice. I'll assume either webforms or and MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend googling "Getting Started with ASP.Net" OR "first asp.net site", you will find a barrage of sites and resources dedicated to the framework.

I guess I would recommend starting here and then going from there: http://www.asp.net/get-started